# Searchbox Text Color in a Listview

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to change the text color of a Searchbox in a Listview...

Even looking in the "Searchbox" listview control the color can't be changed...

```
procedure TfrmList.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
var
  i: integer;
  sb: TSearchBox;
begin
  for i := 0 to ListView1.Controls.Count-1 do
    if ListView1.Controls[I].ClassType = TSearchBox then
    begin
      sb := TSearchBox(ListView1.Controls[i]); 
      Break;
    end;

    sb.FontColor := TAlphaColors.White;
    //or
    sb.TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColors.White;
end;
```

Any ideias? Thanks

Change the color settings in the control of the listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the line shown:

```
procedure TfrmList.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
var
  i: integer;
  sb: TSearchBox;
begin
  for i := 0 to ListView1.Controls.Count-1 do
    if ListView1.Controls[I].ClassType = TSearchBox then
    begin
      sb := TSearchBox(ListView1.Controls[i]); 
      Break;
    end;

    sb.FontColor := TAlphaColors.White;
    //or
    sb.TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColors.White;
    sb.StyledSettings:=sb.StyledSettings-[TStyledSetting.FontColor]; //<--Add this line.
end;
```

This is a common problem that people often get caught on.  Any text settings you change like that will be ignored if the `StyledSettings` property doesn't have the related flag cleared.  When you change, say, the font colour from the Object Inspector, the `StyledSettings` property will be updated automatically.  But when you make the change programatically, you also need to change `StyledSettings` in your code.

Comment: I had looked in styledsettings, but in the wrong way I guess. Your code worked, thanks!

Comment: The easiest solution is to use the style file. The code will be easier to maintain in case of modifications.